# Change google autocomplete dropdown according to position of scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have input with google auto-complete which is located in a header on a landing page. The header is positioned on the bottom of the page when you land and when scroll past that point it sticks to the top of the browser.

I want to be able to change the position of .pac-container according to where my header is i.e when user lands into the page the header is on the bottom of the screen and in the input in it I would like the autocomplete dropdown to be positioned above the input field and when you scroll past the initial landing section the postiion to shift as it is by default so it is on the bottom

Comment: what was the issue ?  what you are done yet ?

Comment: the issue is that by default the drop-down of google auto-complete is showing to the bottom of the input when opened. I would like to dynamically change the drop-down position. I cant really show you what I have done but I have my inputs auto-correct datepickers 

Edit my datepickers and timepickers have this feature enabled by default